# Can an orthogonal matrix that represents a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ have no eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

I know that if the matrix is normal and represents a transformation in a unitary space then it can be unitarily diagonalized, so it must have eigenvalues. Plus, its characteristic polynomial is never a constant, so it has roots according to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

But what if we talk about orthogonal matrices that represent transformations in a Euclidean vector space? Can they have no eigenvalues?

Comment: What does it mean to "have no eigenvalues"?

Comment: The matrix A (which entries' are elements of the field F, and A represents a transformation from the vector space V to V, where V is also over F) has no eigenvalues if for all vectors v in V, that are different from the zero vector, and for all the scalars s from F - Av ≠sv. In other words, if you take a vector that isn't the zero vector, there does not exist a scalar s for which the identity Av = sv holds.

Comment: So, do you mean *real* eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes. The point of the question is - what happens when A*A^t = I, the F=R, and V=R^n for some natural n. Where * denotes standard matrix multiplication, ^t denotes the transpose matrix, and I denotes the identity matrix. Does A ALWAYS have real eigenvalues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see for instance $n=2$ and the matrices in the form $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\ \sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}$ for $\alpha\notin\pi\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

For a $2n$-dimensional space this is true: just consider a generalization of the example of Gae. S.
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}J_1&&&\\
&J_2&&
\\&&\ddots&\\
&&&J_n
\end{pmatrix}\\
J_i=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\alpha_i)&-\sin(\alpha_i)\\
\sin(\alpha_i)&\cos(\alpha_i)
\end{pmatrix};(\alpha_i\notin\pi\mathbb{Z})$$

However, the claim is not true in a $2n+1$-dimensional space; this follows trivially from the fact that a polynomial of odd degree must have at least one real root.

Actually, we can prove something more quite easily:

*Claim*: every $2n+1$ dimensional orthogonal matrix has an eigenvalue $\lambda\in\{-1,+1\};\lambda=\det(T)$.

**Proof:** Since it is orthogonal, $\det(T)=\pm1$. Let us suppose that $\det=1$ (this is not restrictive, since multiplying $T$ by $-1$ changes the sign of the eigenvalues and of the determinant)

$$\det(T-I)=\det(T^{t})\det(T-I)=\det(I-T^{t})=\\=\det(I-T)=(-1)^{2n+1}\det(T-I)=-\det(T-I)$$

Thus $\det(T-I)=0$, and $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue.

In $3$ dimensions, this is known as [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem), since it can be phrased as "every 3-dimensional rotation has a fixed axis".

Comment: Can you please explain the transition- det(I-T^t)=det(I-T)?

Comment: @EliyahuAbadi The determinant is invariant under transpose and the transpose is linear. Thus $\det(I-T^t)=\det((I-T^t)^t)=\det(I-T)$

Comment: Ohhh yes thank you!