# find all eigenvalues for this specific transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner-product space, and $T:V \to V$ a linear transformation for which: 
$T^2 = \frac{T+T^*}{2}$

What are all $T$'s eigenvalues?
($T^*$ notates the conjugate transpose of $T$).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: $T^{*}$ and $T$ are similar.

Comment: @Bombyx mori can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $T^* = 2T^2 - T$. Conclude that $T$ is normal, i.e. $TT^* = T^*T$.

By the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) for normal matrices, conclude that $T$ is unitarily diagonlizable. It follows that because $T^2 = \frac{T + T^*}{2}$, every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ must satisfy
$$
\lambda^2 = \frac{\lambda + \bar \lambda }{2} \implies \lambda^2 =  \operatorname{Re}[\lambda].
$$
What are the solutions to this equation?

Comment: I think you assumed we are over the complex, because as you can see here -[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781932/can-an-orthogonal-matrix-that-represents-a-linear-transformation-from-mathbbr)
not all orthogonal matrices even have eigenvalues at all - so for sure they cannot be diagonalized - but they ARE normal.

Comment: The question regards any inner product space, Unitary or Euclidian.

Comment: @EliyahuAbadi Yes, I assumed we are over the complex numbers; it is rare for those using the inner-product formalism to stick to the real numbers. That said, if $V$ is a real vector space, then $T$ can be uniquely extended to a linear map over the complexification $V_{\Bbb C}$, and the same argument applies. Any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ must satisfy the equation $\lambda^2 = \lambda$.

Comment: if $V$ is a *real* vector space,  from the (very) little I know - scalar multiplication is defined only for real scalars. Leave this specific question aside, how can I refer a *complex* $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue, if $\lambda x$ has no meaning for all $x \in V$ ? Does what you say here mean we should, each time, 'extend' also the definition of scalar multiplication when 'extending' the transformation $T$? how is it costumed to do in general?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "each time". In any case, this is exactly the idea behind "complexification": we can *extend* the vector space and scalar multiplication in order to make the real vector space into a complex vector space, and correspondingly map the real-linear map $T$ to a complex-linear map over this extended space.

Comment: @EliyahuAbadi However, rather than doing that, we can make things much simpler if we simply work with matrices directly. The characteristic polynomial of the matrix associated with $T$ will be the same whether we think of the matrix $T$ as one corresponding to a real-linear map or to a complex-linear map, the only difference is whether or not we include complex eigenvalues in our consideration. If the matrix of $T$ has $0,1$ as its only complex eigenvalues, then the linear transformation $T$ can only have eigenvalues $0,1$.